# Trying to filter Table visual by tasks which are late i.e Date [Scheduled Finish] < Now

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

While filtering there is no option to match with current date via `NOW()` method, date can only be picked from date picker. So I created new column and tried filtering out through:

```
Column = IF(SampleTaskList[Scheduled Finish] < Now(), SampleTaskList[Scheduled Finish].[Date], "")
```

But it returns error ***Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.*** Whats the issue? The returned type is date as **[Scheduled Finish]** is date and blank is returned otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the difference between a date and a string. You are returning a date for TRUE and a string `""` for FALSE.

Try `Blank()` instead of the string.

```
Column = IF(SampleTaskList[Scheduled Finish] < Now(), SampleTaskList[Scheduled Finish].[Date], Blank())
```

Comment: Why should I upvote your question? It's not a particularly good question. Not EVERY question deserves an upvote, even if it is answered. See the discussions on Meta.